# Doctrine Entity from other Bundle in Symfony Controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to use the Entity of another Bundle in my Symfony Controller:

```
use Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Neighbour;
use AppBundle\Entity\Home;

class TestController extends Controller {

    public function testAction(Home $home, Neighbour $neighbour) { 

        //
    }
}
```

but this throws an 404 Error:

```
Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Neighbour object not found
```

this is different to a real not existing object like NeighbourX, there it throws an 500 error:

```
Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Neighbour does not exist
```

The object exists, and it should work, because this works:

```
use Acme\TestBundle\Entity\Neighbour;
use AppBundle\Entity\Home;

class TestController extends Controller {

    public function testAction(Home $home) { 

        $thread = new ForumThread();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I already found the answer myself. I had to specify the route variable:

```
/home/{id}/neighbour/{nid} #before
/home/{id}/neighbour/{neighbour} #after
```

But I don't fully understand it. Why doesn't {id} has to be {home}? Is {id} just the first parameter-id by default?

And why is the error message that misleading..

Comment: I believe the parameter names have to be the same as those specified in the route.

Comment: it should be so, but why is {id} and $home working together? Btw, that is the way the CRUD has been automatically created by symfony